# Excel PowerPivot - filtering on constant instead of numeric value

Tags: excel-2013, powerpivot

In MS Excel 2013 PowerPivot I have a tables, provided by external data connection to SQL server. Having row data in "tabl" powerpivot table I am doing a lot of calculations based on static numeric values like:

```
Total1#:=Calculate(CountRows(Tabl),Tabl[requestID]=1,Tabl[Status]=3,Tabl[Flag]<>0),Tabl[userID]=15)

Total2#:=Calculate(CountRows(Tabl),Tabl[requestID]=1,Tabl[Status]=3,Tabl[Flag]<>0),Tabl[userID]=16)
```

So when datasource IDs changing I have to modify dozens formulas one by one just to replace old IDs with new one. Can someone advice how to use some kind of constants / calculated values instead, to do something like this:

```
Total1#:=Calculate(CountRows(Tabl),Tabl[requestID]=CONST1,Tabl[Status]=CONST2,Tabl[Flag]<>CONST3),Tabl[userID]=CONST4)
```

Is it possible in PowerPivot?

Comment: One option is to create a linked table (in your document itself, then add to powerpivot as a linked table) that acts as a dimension table (or lookup table). That way you can edit the constants on the spreadsheet, refresh your powerpivot and all will updated.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! This is what I really need, and it works great when I do like this: CalculatedField:=LOOKUPVALUE(Table[ID];[Entity];"Key").but seems lookup value doesnt works

Comment: when I`m trying to use it for filtering. Formula Total1#:=Calculate(CountRows(Tabl);Tabl[requestID]=LOOKUPVALUE(LinkedTable[ID];[Entity];"Key")) throws an error "Semantic Eror: Function "Calculate" has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed."

Comment: And here is an error explanantion with advice how to fix it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn727121.aspx


@guitarthrower thanks again!

Comment: no worries. Great follow up work! You should right it up as an answer so others can learn from your work